# tkinter PIL image is not shown up in class

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I can't show up the Image in tkinter PIL class.
Image is packed or placed successfully but it is not showing up.
windowxp wall paper and a man's face are not shown.
I made message box when click his face.
So if I click the location, message box is showing up. But picture is not showing up. Just location :(
I use windows 64bit and Python 3.6
I am Korean. I'm not goot at English.... Please understand me.
Please help me

This is right display: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spBf9.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

    ##함수
class Mainwindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("김상곤이 좋아하는 꿈꾸는 학과 과목 문제 맞추기♡")
        self.geometry("1600x900")
        self.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)


        wall = tk.PhotoImage(file="gif/bg.gif")
        labelwall = tk.Label(self, image = wall)
        labelwall.place(x=0, y=0)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        def func_make():
            messagebox.showinfo("제작자", "김재온, 정성윤, 안예진, 이소유, 우연서")

        def func_exit():
            window.quit()
            window.destroy()

        mainMenu=Menu(self)
        fileMenu=Menu(mainMenu)
        self.config(menu=mainMenu)
        mainMenu.add_cascade(label="파일", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="제작자", command=func_make)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="종료", command=func_exit)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (MainPage, QuizPage):
            page_name=F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name]=frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("MainPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):

        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def 국어():

        page == 1

    subject=['국어', '과학', '역사', '사회', '기술']  

#색이나 위치 숫자 설정

mint="#99FFFF"
subjectsize=30
subjectbutton=60

##위젯

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        def clickksk(event):
                messagebox.showinfo("김상곤", "아주 좋아요^^")

        labeltitle=tk.Label(self, text=
                            """김상곤이 좋아하는 꿈꾸는
학과 과목 문제 맞추기♡""", font=("궁서체", 35), bg="#8DFD73")

        ksk=tk.PhotoImage(file="gif/ksk.gif")
        labelksk=tk.Label(self, image=ksk)                           

        labelksk.place(x=400-subjectbutton, y=200)
        labelksk.bind("<Button>", clickksk)
        labelhow=tk.Label(self, text="게임방법!                   ", font=("맑은 고딕", 30), bg="#FFE400")
        labelexplain=tk.Label(self, text=
        """원하는 과목을 택해 클릭한후,
        OX퀴즈를 풀면 됩니다^^
        난이도=중3""", font=("고딕체", 25), bg="#FFE400")   

        btKorean=tk.Button(self, text="국어", font=("양재블럭체", subjectsize), bg=mint,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("QuizPage"))

        btScience=tk.Button(self, text="과학", font=("양재블럭체", subjectsize), bg=mint)
        btHistory=tk.Button(self, text="역사", font=("양재블럭체", subjectsize), bg=mint)
        btSocial=tk.Button(self, text="사회", font=("양재블럭체", subjectsize), bg=mint)
        bttech=tk.Button(self, text="기술", font=("양재블럭체", subjectsize), bg=mint)

        ##pack하는 장소(코드 순차대로)

        labeltitle.place(relx= 0.25, rely=0.02, relwidth=0.5)
        labelhow.place(x=610-subjectbutton, y=200, relwidth=0.3)
        labelexplain.place(x=610-subjectbutton, y=260, relwidth=0.3)

        btKorean.place(x=400-subjectbutton, y=600)
        btScience.place(x=600-subjectbutton, y=600)
        btHistory.place(x=800-subjectbutton, y=600)
        btSocial.place(x=1000-subjectbutton, y=600)
        bttech.place(x=1200-subjectbutton, y=600)

        btKorean.bind("<Button-1>")
        btScience.bind("<Button-1>")
        btHistory.bind("<Button-1>")
        btSocial.bind("<Button-1>")
        bttech.bind("<Button-1>")

class QuizPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        OB=PhotoImage(file="gif/OB.gif")
        XR=PhotoImage(file="gif/XR.gif")

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        buttonOB=Button(self, image=OB)
        buttonXR=Button(self, image=XR)

        buttonOB.place()
        buttonXR.place()         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Mainwindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not import tkinter twice. This line `from tkinter import *`... I think you should just let it go.

Comment: I would also like to point out that the use of `place()` is very bad for maintainability and dealing with screens of different sizes. You really should use `grid()` here and define proper spacing between widgets so it is more dynamic.

Comment: Often when I use images in tkinter I need to let python know it can look in a local directory buy putting a `.` in front of the local file path. So this: `"gif/bg.gif"` should probably look like this `"./gif/bg.gif"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is you are using two subclassed frames and using grid to manage them but the main application window is not expanding the grid area. You need to add the following to `MainWindow.__init__`:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

so that the (0,0) cell is expanded to fill all the available space. Then your currently selected frame will expand into that region as it has `sticky='NSWE'` set in the grid method call.

Where you define `container` you are both packing and gridding. You have to only use one. However, this looks like dead code. Maybe you intended to put the subclassed frames into this container at one time.

Also, you cannot just call `buttonXR.place()`, you need to give it a position. For instance: `buttonXR.place(x=1, y=1)`.